# Implement items ordering in Django

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

Suppose, I want to build a simple TODO-app. I want to make it possible to create todo-items, and also it should be possible to rearrange items manually.

I made following model:

```py
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Now, I need to add a special field, let's call it `order`, to keep custom ordering. It should be unique, and it should be greater for any new record, so I tried to make an `AutoField`.

```py
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    order = models.AutoField(primary_key=False)
```

But it turned out that Django doesn't support several auto fields for a single model.

I guess, it should be possible to write custom raw SQL code and use Postgres sequences directly, but it would look really ugly, and I don't want to write DB-specific code for such simple functionality.

So, here is a question: what is a common way to implement items ordering in Django? It sounds like a very common requirement, and, I think, it should be a simple way to do this.

Comment: A SerialField for Postgres [is being developed](https://github.com/django/django/pull/7525), and it seems to be part of a more comprehensive effort (see talk about DEP). I also saw a post about [Django second AutoField](http://schinckel.net/2015/05/17/django-second-autofield/) that was interesting.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out there is no straightforward way to implement this in Django. There are packages which help you, like [this one](https://github.com/bfirsh/django-ordered-model)

But I would recommend just look at their model implementation and fit your needs. [models.py](https://github.com/bfirsh/django-ordered-model/blob/master/ordered_model/models.py)

Comment: It's a pity. I'll look to it closely, but, after a breef look, it doesn't seem to be concurrent-transactions-safe.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Item.objects.count()` to automatically increment your field. Plug it in the save() method of your model so that your field is calculated each time you create an instance.

Comment: I don't this is a good idea, because this could lead to duplicated `order` values in case of concurrent transations

Comment: you may want to take a look at this. https://medium.com/@hakibenita/how-to-manage-concurrency-in-django-models-b240fed4ee2 There are different approach you can use to avoid this, depending on your application.